# Filter unique values conditional on groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
id  L1  L2
1   A   B
1   A   C
1   A   D
1   B   B
1   B   C
1   B   D
2   D   A
2   D   F
```

I want to filter out any `L2` value that's in `L1`, but only within same `id` group. So for `id=1`, we filter out `L2=B`, but keep `L2=D`. For `id=2`, we keep `L2=A`.

Output should be like:

```
id  L1  L2
1   A   C
1   A   D
1   B   C
1   B   D
2   D   A
2   D   F
```

Comment: Are you using Pandas for that table? If not, what *are* you using for this datastructure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using `pandas`:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[~x.L2.isin(x.L1)]).reset_index(drop=True)

   id L1 L2
0   1  A  C
1   1  A  D
2   1  B  C
3   1  B  D
4   2  D  A
5   2  D  F
```